# How to show hidden div in php

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

I have `lecturer`div. I hidden this div. After that `if($user->hasPermission('admin'))` this function is true i want to show `lecturer` div.I will put stars`****` like this. I want show div for that place.

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = new User();

if($user->isLoggedIn()) {

?>
<li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>

 <div class="lecturer" id="lecturer" style="display: none;">
  <label for="studentID">Student ID</label>
 </div>

<?php

if($user->hasPermission('admin')){
echo '<p>You are the admin</p>';
********I want to show lecturer dive here*************
}

}else {


echo '<p>You need to <a href="login.php">login</a> or <a href="register.php">register</a>';

}
```

Comment: if you only need to show that div if the condition is true,then y dont you put the div inside the if condition??

Comment: use `echo "<div>Lecturer</div>"` where you put star (*)

Comment: hi, `Vimal`, I have to show two div. there fore, I cant put the div inside the if condition.

Comment: @Loke is Lecturer div has something to do with if condition

Comment: @ Harikrishnan N, what I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = new User();

if($user->isLoggedIn()) {

?>
<li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>

 <div class="lecturer" id="lecturer" style="display: none;">
  <label for="studentID">Student ID</label>
 </div>

    <?php

    if($user->hasPermission('admin')){
    echo '<p>You are the admin</p>';
    echo '<div>Lecturer</div>';
    } 
    }else {


echo '<p>You need to <a href="login.php">login</a> or <a href="register.php">register</a>';

}
```

Comment: @Loke Are you getting "You are the admin" displayed on screen

Comment: @Loke did you try my code? Is not the "Lecturer" not being displayed?

Comment: @Loke replace my div with the `div` you need to show when the user is `admin`